# how to show the results in different frames only by using one function?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have this code to change the title of the frame. I have two pages here. In `PageOne` class, we get the title and by pressing the button, the title changes. And, we can use the `Go to page two` button to navigate to `PageTwo`. here also we can do the same.

Here is my question, how I can define only **one function** instead of using function `add1()` in `PageOne`, and function `add2()` in `PageTwo`. I mean I only define one function on `PageOne` and use the same function in `PageTwo`, and show the results in the `frame2`.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.number2 = tk.StringVar()


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.minsize(700, 700)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()

        self.data = Data()

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self.data)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.frames[PageOne].page_button.config(command=self.go_to_page_two)
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def go_to_page_two(self):
        self.show_frame(PageTwo)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        entry1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.data.number1)
        entry1.pack()

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="click", command=self.add1)
        self.button1.pack()

        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, height=200, width=200, borderwidth=2)
        self.frame1.pack()

        self.page_button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two")
        self.page_button.pack()

    def add1(self):
        self.frame1.config(text=str(self.data.number1.get()))


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        entry2 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.data.number2)
        entry2.pack()

        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text="click", command=self.add2)
        self.button2.pack()

        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self, height=200, width=200, borderwidth=2)
        self.frame2.pack()

    def add2(self):
        self.frame2.config(text=str(self.data.number2.get()))

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do in this way:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = tk.StringVar()


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.minsize(700, 700)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()

        self.data = Data()

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne,):
            frame = F(container, self.data)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        entry1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.data.number)
        entry1.pack()

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="click", command=lambda : self.add(self.frame1, data.number))
        self.button1.pack()

        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, height=200, width=200, borderwidth=2)
        self.frame1.pack()

        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text="click", command=lambda : self.add(self.frame2, data.number))
        self.button2.pack()

        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self, height=200, width=200, borderwidth=2)
        self.frame2.pack()

    def add(self, frame, data):
        frame.config(text=str(self.data.number.get()))


app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```